# Multiple Loops in WordPress. Second loop not resetting

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, sidebar

I've created a custom post type with custom fields inside Wordpress.  I created a new page template that runs through a loop and that works great.  I'm trying to add a similar loop to the home page's sidebar but it doesn't work correctly.

First, the working code on my own page template.

```
<h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
<?php $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
$event_query = new WP_query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish&meta_key=event_date&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=' . $todaysDate . '&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC');
?> 

<ul id="featured_event_list">
<?php if ($event_query->have_posts()): ?>
<?php while ($event_query->have_posts()) : $event_query->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_featuring', true) ) : ?>
        <strong>Featuring:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_featuring', true) ?><br />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true) ) : ?>
        <?php $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
        $new_event_date = date("F j, Y",strtotime($event_date)); ?>
        <strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $new_event_date ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_end_date', true) ) : ?>
        <?php $event_end_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_end_date', true);
        $new_event_end_date = date("F j, Y",strtotime($event_end_date)); ?>
        - <?php echo $new_event_end_date ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <br />
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_time', true) ) : ?>
        <strong>Time:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_time', true) ?><br />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_location', true) ) : ?>
        <strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_location', true) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<li>Sorry, no upcoming events.</li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

That works fine, but when I put a modified version of that code as a widget inside of functions.php, it doesn't work:

```
<?php
function eventsWidget() { ?>
    <div class="uwf_widget">
        <h3 class="events"><span>Featured Events</span></h3>
        <ul>
<?php
        $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
        $event_widget_query = new WP_query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=2&post_status=publish&meta_key=event_date&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=' . $todaysDate . '&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC');
?> 
        <?php if ($event_widget_query->have_posts()) :?>
        <?php while ($event_widget_query->have_posts()) : $event_widget_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
            $new_event_date = date("F j",strtotime($event_date)); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $new_event_date; ?> &nbsp;&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <li>Sorry, no upcoming events.</li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
            <p class="more"><a href="/about-us/events/">more events &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, if I put that code inside the normal sidebar (instead of on the homepage) - it works fine.  So, clearly there is something wrong with multiple loops on the home page and the sidebar.  If I simplify the widget so it only grabs 2 "events" it will grab two posts (regardless of the post_type).  I've tried rewind_posts and wp_reset_query, so I'm not sure what else to try?

Comment: still stuck on this.  If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this.  I used get_posts and built an array and for some reason it now works on the home page.

```
<?php
function eventsWidget() {?>
    <div class="uwf_widget">
        <h3 class="events"><span>Featured Events</span></h3>
        <ul>
<?php
        global $post;
        $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
        $event_args = array('post_type' => 'events', 
                            'numberposts' => 2,
                            'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'meta_compare' => '>=',
                            'meta_value' => $todaysDate,
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                            'order'=> 'ASC');
        $event_widget_query = get_posts( $event_args );
        foreach ($event_widget_query as $post) : setup_postdata($event_widget_query); ?>
            <?php $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
            $new_event_date = date("F j",strtotime($event_date)); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $new_event_date; ?> &nbsp;&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
            <p class="more"><a href="/about-us/events/">more events &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it was caused by wp_hook 'pre_get_posts'

```
<?php function custom_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'events', 'pages') );

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_get_posts' );
?>
```

To solve this problem you can remove this filter before your WP_Query and add it again after this query.

```
<?php

remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_get_posts' );

/*
 * Your new WP_Query
 */

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_get_posts' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `global post;` declaration at the start of your function.

```
<?php
function eventsWidget() { 
    global $post; ?>
    <div class="uwf_widget">
        <h3 class="events"><span>Featured Events</span></h3>
        <ul>
<?php
        $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
        $event_widget_query = new WP_query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=2&post_status=publish&meta_key=event_date&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=' . $todaysDate . '&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC');
?> 
        <?php if ($event_widget_query->have_posts()) :?>
        <?php while ($event_widget_query->have_posts()) : $event_widget_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
            $new_event_date = date("F j",strtotime($event_date)); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $new_event_date; ?> &nbsp;&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <li>Sorry, no upcoming events.</li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
            <p class="more"><a href="/about-us/events/">more events &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I haven't tried that before.  Unfortunately, I still get the same result.

Comment: What output do you get from this loop?

Comment: "Sorry, no upcoming events."  If I simplify the query to $event_widget_query = new WP_query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=2'); I get the two most recent posts (not the two most recent events).  So, it seems to still be pulling from the home page loops.

Comment: FYI, this does solve one of the issues I was running into (described in the other thread here).

Answer (score 0):

Try a `rewind_posts()` after your `endwhile` in whichever loop is used first (if your sidebar call is at the bottom of your template, do it in your page template, or the opposite if the sidebar is called at the top).

Another approach:

```
<?php
function eventsWidget() { ?>
    <div class="uwf_widget">
        <h3 class="events"><span>Featured Events</span></h3>
        <ul>
        <?php $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
        query_posts('$post_type=event&posts_per_page=2');
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php while ($have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
            $new_event_date = date("F j",strtotime($event_date)); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $new_event_date; ?> &nbsp;&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <li>Sorry, no upcoming events.</li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
            <p class="more"><a href="/about-us/events/">more events &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I've tried that and just tried it again and I get the same result, which is "Sorry, no upcoming events." If I simplify the query to $event_widget_query = new WP_query('post_type=events&posts_per_page=2'); I get the two most recent posts (not the two most recent events). So, it seems to still be pulling from the home page loops.

Comment: Just for fun, can you use an associative array in the WP_query string? `'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 2`

Comment: That was contained as an array, right? Sorry - `$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) )`

Comment: Yes, except I kept the name as $event_widget_query.  If I change it to wp_query and update the function - it not only ignores post_type, but also ignores posts_per_page and pulls in the 4 (site default) most recent posts.

Comment: Try another approach - going to edit my answer in a few moments.

Comment: I appreciate your time.  I've been struggling with this for a few days now.  I'm relatively new with php, but I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: Not a problem, I've had enough assistance on here with things like this that it's only fair to try in return =)

Comment: I'm getting a validation error on line 13 (endwhile;else) and 19(}) above.  If I change my code from wp_query to query posts and remove the references to $event_widget_query, I still get the same two posts being pulled in- even after adding a rewind_posts to home.php.

Comment: Updated one more time - it might have been a really obvious issue. Normally, when creating a post type, you name the post type itself using the singular - 'event', not 'events'. Changed in mine, give it a try, but that would explain that behaviour exactly. The errors you encountered, I corrected, forgot to remove those references but you already figured that out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result.  I'm guessing something must be wrong on home.php that is leaving the loop open.

Comment: It gets even more confusing.  If I call to the function with sidebar.php (not sidebar-home.php) - it shows the Events but has the wrong dates.  If I copy and paste the code for the function in sidebar.php - it displays perfectly.

Comment: dogbert's suggestion below of putting in global $post; does fix the sidebar.php paste vs function issue.